# Laplace transform with time shift property

Tags: laplace-transform

[image: Transform this into time domain]

[image: This is the answer]

[image: time shift]

ok so i have no idea how the inverse laplace went from $F(s)$ to $f(t)$. I understand $\frac{c}{s^2}$ => $ct$, and $\frac{b}{s}$ => $b$, but the $e^{-as}$ is what gets me. In my Laplace tables I know it has something to do with the time shift.

If you expand the first term of $F(s)$ you get 
\begin{equation}
\frac{c}{s^2}-\frac{c}{s^2}e^{-as}.
\end{equation}
 So in this case for $e^{-as}F(s)$, $F(s)$ would be $\frac{c}{s^2}$ correct? Then wouldn't the Laplace transform be $ct1(t-a)$? The time shift is confusing the hell out of me.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} (e^{-as}F(s)) = f(t-a)u(t-a)$$

- For $F(s) = \dfrac{1}{s^2}$, we would have $f(t) = t$.

Now, because of the $e^{-as}$ term, we have to apply the time-shift property to $f(t)$, by replacing $t = t-a$ using the above and get:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(-c\dfrac{1}{s^2}e^{-a s}\right) = -c(t-a)u(t-a)$$

- For $c\dfrac{1}{s^2}$, we have $f(t) = t$, but no time shift, hence:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(c\dfrac{1}{s^2}\right) = ct$$

- For $-b\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-as}$, we have $f(t) = 1$, and a time shift, hence:

$$\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left(-b\dfrac{1}{s} e^{-as}\right) = -bu(t-a)$$

Comment: but if f(t)=t, wouldn't it be -c(t)? Why is it -c(t-a)? This part is really confusing for me.

Comment: the last term -b/s(e^-at) is -b1(t-a) because the inverse laplace of 1/s is the unit step, hence no change in time. (-c/s^2)(e^-as) has inverse laplace of -c(t-a)1(t-a) because the inverse laplace of 1/s^2 is t, hence time does change and needs to follow the f(t-a)1(t-a) form. Thanks a lot amzoti.

Comment: i tried to click the orange triangle but it doensn't let me. i think my account too new man sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

$ct*1(t-a)$ is not the Laplace transform of $\frac{c}{s^2}e^{-as}$, because you haven't shift the function.
 The function is $f(t)=t$, if you want to shift this function of a quantity $a$ you obtain:
     $f(t-a)=t-a$

In the second part the function is just $f(t)=1$, if you shift this function you obtain always $f(t-a)=1$, because is constant all over the axis $t$.